# Roboto font doesn't render well in Chrome but looks good in FireFox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I'm using Roboto font-type from google-fonts and have set my font-weight to be 300px (this doesn't make so much of a difference to the boldness). In FireFox, the texts looks quite good, on the other hand, it doesn't look too good in Chrome.

A screenshot of the both browsers with the texts attached below:

Comment: Fixed now! Google released a new version of Chrome that fixed this issue.